# preg_match failing for me when checking different parts of the string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This `preg_match` will never work even though I think its the right thing.

I'm trying to check a string so that it's structured as follows

```
$value = US 01 02 1406034963 .JPG //I've put spaces in. The real one is below.
```

So:

The first part (US) is alphabets, only two characters from a-z

The second part (01) is a value 00 or 01

The third part (02) is digits 0-9 from 2 - 10 (can be 2 to 10 digits long)

The fourth part (1406034963) is a 10 digit figure, and only 10 digits

The fifth part is .jpg or .jpeg or .png. or .gif

But, my function always returns false. Can you please help?

```
//
function preset($value) {
    if(preg_match('/^[a-z]{2}[00|01][0-9]{2,10}[0-9]{10}[.jpg|.jpeg|.png.|.gif]$/',$value)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$value = 'US01021406034963.JPG';

if(preset($value)) {
    echo 'Yeah!';
} else {
    echo 'Boo!';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[]` denotes a character class. Simply put, a character class is a way of denoting a set of characters in such a way that **one character** of the set is matched.

You're trying to use alternation inside character classes. It will not work as you expect it to. For example, the regex `[00|01]` would match `0`, the literal character `|`, or `1`, and ***not*** `00` or `01`.

To match either of the set, you can simply use grouping. In this case, you're not going to use the matched text anywhere, so you can use non-capturing groups. `(?:00|01)` is a non-capturing group that will match either `00` or `01`. You can also shorten it and write just `0[01]`, but that totally depends on your taste.

And currently, your expression only matches lower-case strings. If you want it to work with upper-case, or even mixed-case strings, you can simply use the `i` modifier. It will make the pattern match the string case-insensitively.

You can simplify your function to just:

```
function preset($value) {
    return (bool) preg_match('/^[a-z]{2}(?:00|01)[0-9]{2,10}[0-9]{10}\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$/i',$value);
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/170626)

Comment: @anubhava: That's not really required, no. `preg_match()` returns 1, 0, or boolean false. I just wanted the function to be consistent, i.e. *always* return a boolean :)

Comment: Everything works fine, except for the fourth part. Try adding an extra 0 there, and it's still true(the one before the extension checks).

Comment: US 01 02 14060349630 .jpg This shouldn't match. Because part four has 11 digits (spaces are for convenience). Part four should only be 10 digits long (and only 10). Part 3 can be 2 to 10 digits long.

Comment: @Norman: I see what you mean. Is it okay to assume that part 4 will always start with `1`?

Comment: Its a random number actually. Cant say if it'll always begin with 1 :-)

Comment: Can you not change `[0-9]{2,10}` to `[0-9]{2}` ? [Example](http://regex101.com/r/oQ7qZ6/1)

Comment: That part can be anything from 2 to 10 digits as the number increments

Comment: @Norman: The regex will require some sorts of delimiters to make the distinction between different parts.

Comment: I thought of the same thing. I just use this for now then.

Comment: If it did have a delimiter like a `-` after the third part how would it be done (the regex)?

Comment: +1 for taking the time to write a full, clear explanation. :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot place whole words inside of a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), use a non-capturing group instead.

```
/^[a-z]{2}0[01][0-9]{2,10}[0-9]{10}\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$/i
```

Comment: Same here. Try adding an extra digit to the part before the extension checks, and it's still true. Even though it's 11 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You are erroneously using square (character class) instead of round (alternation) brackets in some places:

`[00|01]` should be `(00|01)`.

`[.jpg|.jpeg|.png.|.gif]` should be `\.(jpe?g|png|gif)`.